# Find number of iterations in nested for-loops

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

We are given a pseudocode:

```
for ( int x1 = 1 ; x1 <= n ; x1++ )
   for ( int x2 = x1 ; x2 <= n ; x2++ ) 
      for ( int x3 = x2 ; x3 <= n ; x3++ )
    ……
       ……
          ……
        for ( int xm = x(m-1) ; xm <= n ; xm++ )
            it++ ;
```

We are required to find the number of iterations for $n=26$ and $m=25$.

I tried taking small cases and observed that for $m$ nested loops :
No. of iterations
= $$I = \sum_{i_m=1}^n(\sum_{i_{m-1}=1}^n(...\sum_{i_1=1}^n(1))$$

But I have no idea how to perform this for a large number of nested loops. Can someone suggest an alternative way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of iterations equals the number of $m$-tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ for which $1\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\dots\leq x_m\leq n$. When we define $y_i:=x_i+i-1$ for $i=1,\dots,m$, then we get the $m$-tuples $(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ for which $1\leq y_1<y_2<\dots<y_m\leq n+m-1$. This is equal to the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,m+n-1\}$ with exactly $m$ elements, which is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$.

In your case, we get $\binom{50}{25}=126410606437752$.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence counts the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n-1,m)$, and this is given by $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$.

This is because each `for` loop represents a column height, and iterates from $1\dots n$, which is translated to $0\dots n-1$.

As this doesn't force the final column to be of height $n$, another column is added of height $n$, this gives $m+1$ columns, and we iterate from $0\dots m$.

Finally, we trace a path over the tops of each column to get the paths.

Comment: That is not true. For example, when n=m=2 then there are 2 paths from (0,0) to (1,1)=(m-1,n-1) but $\binom{3}{1}=3$.

Comment: Fixed, we need to add a final column to force the result.